# jqgrid set the whole grid in inline mode edition

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am trying to build a grid and set certain cells in edit mode and some disabled then apply editRow to activate the edits but it does not work.

Here is the code I have so far on the complete event :

```
gridComplete: function(){
    jQuery("#list<?php echo $type_index; ?>").jqGrid('setFrozenColumns');
    var ids = $(this).jqGrid('getDataIDs');
    for (var i=0; i<ids.length; i++) {
            var id=ids[i];
            for (var j=3; j<<?php echo (3+($color_index*2)); ?>; j=j+2){
                    if ( $(this).jqGrid('getCell', id, j) === '' ) {
                            var cm = $(this).jqGrid('getColProp',j+1);
                            cm.editable = false;
                    }
            }
            $(this).jqGrid("editRow", id );
    }
```

For some reason, jqgrid does not care if i set the column in edit mode or not, everything is just as if all columns are enabled.

Regards,

Comment: Which advantage have the user if you do this? Many rows can be changed, but be in unsaved state. The user can't use sorting by click on the column header. You can't use paging or you have to implement some custom actions in `onPaging`, .... I can continue. Why you want to do this? The only advantage is the user sees that one can make some changes on your page, but the user should know this already during opening the page of you can inform the user about the possibility to edit by click/double-click on any row/cell.

Comment: No paging function necessary, the sorting is disabled. This is a requirement to be able to edit multiple row without having to click on each rows or cells.

Comment: What about saving the rows? If the user clicks on one row edit some fields, then clicks on another row and edit some other fields, then one will have multiple **unsaved** rows. If the user just close the web browser or goes to another page in the window then the unsaved changes will be discarded, but the user will still suppose that the changes are done. Is it your requirement too? If you still want to implement such behavior then I don't understand your problem. Why you use some strange `editable: false`? Do you set `editable: true` in all columns of `colModel`? What is your problem?

Comment: Yes it is because it is for an order form, only when the user click a submit button all the fields should be saved. Actually my problem is that some cells should be editable and some should not, that s why i tried to set first all the necessary cols to editable: false then set the row into inline mode edit. I set all the columns as editable true by default.

Comment: The problem which you describe depend on the version of jqGrid and the fork of jqGrid, which you use. I develop [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) since the end of 2014. I implemented support of `editable` value as callback function together with many other new features. See [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/editable-property-of-colModel-as-function) for more details. You code could be very simple in the case. You can use free jqGrid from CDN (see [another wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)).

Comment: OK, thanks for your time. I will have a look at free-jqGrid.